# automatically receive RSS feeded ffiles from SEC.gov, as small program as possible, preferably in python, any suggestions?

Tags: python, file, hyperlink, rss

specifically, i want to keep all the xml files that RSS publish in sec.gov, in as little code as i can.
any package? tools? approach?

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you prefer Python, [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to the rescue!

If you just want to save the pure XML files, you can just use a command line tool such as curl:

`curl -O http://www.sec.gov/rss/news/press.xml`

You can also look at other RSS Python packages such as feedparser:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/feedparser

You really have a lot of options, but you will need to be more specific as to what you have tried.

Comment: thanks. I got feedparser worked out for me.